# IList<T> Count property invokes GetHashCode() (using NHibernate)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, ilist

I get a strange issue.
As the code shown below, list contain a lot of items.
The code `list.Count == 0;` sometimes will invoke `GetHashCode` function of the item in the list.

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IList<T> list)
{
    if (list == null)
        return true;

    return list.Count == 0;
}

class Item
{
    int id;
    int Version;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
          unchecked
          {
                 return (Id * 397) ^ Version;
          }
    }
}
```

I don't know why this could be happened?

Thanks a lot for any infomation.

The list sometime contain nothing, the Count of list is 0.
The list contain NHibernate item.
[NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag]

Comment: Use stack trace to find out the caller

Comment: No, `List.Count` won't invoke `GetHashCode`. What made you think it did?

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks for verifying that for me. I was thinking to myself, that's impossible!

Comment: It's also depends on concrete implementation of `IList<T>`.

Comment: I also think it can't happen, but sometime it can invoke the item GetHashCode. what is more, the caller shown in the stack trace showing external code.

Comment: @Michael Instead of some vague traces of information, why don't you post a relevant code that demonstrates the issue? Please refer to [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: What is the concrete type of the list? An arbitrary IList-of-T implementation could choose to do just about anything. One thing it might choose to to is have a dual implementation including keyed access, thus buiding an internal hash table of the items. So again: what is the concrete list?

Comment: @Marc Gravell The list contain NHibernate entity

Comment: @Michael I'm not interested in what the list contains. I'm interested in what the list itself is.

Comment: @MarcGravell list is PersistentGenericBag. I think I know what happened. Thank you. Because of the lazy loading, the Count property of PersistentGenericBag may trigger database request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Shad says in comments it has to do with the implementation of your `IList<T>`. I went and checked source code of `PersistentGenericBag<T>` and it looks like this:

```
public class PersistentGenericBag<T> : PersistentBag, IList<T> { }
```

And `PersistentBag` looks like this:

```
public class PersistentBag : AbstractPersistentCollection, IList { }
```

The `Count` property is defined in this class `PersistentBag` which looks like:

```
public int Count
{
    get { return ReadSize() ? CachedSize : bag.Count; }
}
```

where `bag` is a simple `IList` and `CachedSize` merely an `int` property. So everything has got to do with `ReadSize` which is defined in `AbstractPersistentCollection` which looks like:

```
protected virtual bool ReadSize()
{
    if (!initialized)
    {
        if (cachedSize != -1 && !HasQueuedOperations)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            ThrowLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected();
            // the below line it has to be.
            CollectionEntry entry = session.PersistenceContext.GetCollectionEntry(this); 
            ICollectionPersister persister = entry.LoadedPersister;
            if (persister.IsExtraLazy)
            {
                if (HasQueuedOperations)
                {
                    session.Flush();
                }
                cachedSize = persister.GetSize(entry.LoadedKey, session);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    Read();
    return false;
}
```

The `session` variable is of type `ISessionImplementor`, so everything will depend on how it is implemented. The `GetCollectionEntry(bag)` should be a call to get the item from the bag (a bag is a collection structure which allows duplicate elements) which will have to perform some equality checks before retrieving it, which in turn will have to call `GetHashCode` of the item.

I have no idea what they do with all this, but it has got to do with the above method.

References:
[PersistentGenericBag](http://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/4312623)
[PersistentBag](http://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/4312615)
[AbstractPersistentCollection](http://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/26535461)